# How do I scroll entire page from link to 75% as percent in an animated scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, hyperlink

How do I scroll my entire page, using a link to 75% as percent in an animated scroll?

I want it to scroll 75% on my page and to write it in percent on the code and at the same time to have it animated as it is.

The animation works, except I cannot get the scrolling to work in percent.

**My JavaScript Query code:**

```
function scrollTo75() {
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
        var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    console.log(height);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: height/100 - window.innerHeight/75
    }, 200);
}
```

**My Body Code:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="scrollTo75();" title="Scroll 75%">75%</a>
```

Comment: I have edited it now. I mean JavaScript and JQuery, not juts Java. I put Java in of mistake when I put JavaScript in as tag.

Answer (score 1):

Change `scrollTop: height/100 - window.innerHeight/75` to `scrollTop: height * .75`:

```
function scrollTo75() {
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
        var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    console.log(height);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: height * .75
    }, 200);
}
```

**EDIT:** If you need to use 75 instead of .75, you can just do `scrollTop: height * (75 / 100)`

Comment: It sort of works and not. On a full page it works, but when using the same code on a shorter page with a div, I get all the way down instead of 75%. So it has to work relatively to the div too not only to the page. However on a page without a div it worked. But it needs to work both in div and non-div.

Comment: @SeekLoad Hmm not sure I understand the requirements. Please update your question with your HTML to show where the div is and what your expectation is for scrolling within it.

Comment: No need, because I am searching for a universal solution that works both within the div and outside of it. The div itself is nothing special, it is just different length that is all, the rest it is a normal div, no java and nothing else to it except normal CSS measurements and transparent background. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Problem is that this solution of yours does not calculate 70% when the length of the page differs. The div has a tree menu inside of it and the tree menu size will differ depending if it is opened or not. The menu itself has no scroll because it uses the scroll of the div box.

Comment: But as I said, the div is a normal div box made to 100% in height. Ah I FORGOT TO MENTION, the div box is put in an iframe from were you can access the menu.

Comment: Its for this page:  http://www.seekload.50webs.com just look at the menu I made.
I was wanting to find an universal scroll that would work both for the page and the menu. However the new version of the page I am now working on, has only 2 iframes, not like the old one online now. But the menu is the same (just different size), and this is a problem about the menu.
New version will be mobile friendly because old version is not.
So for SOURCE CODES just go to my page online and see.
Online I have not added the scroll, but you get the picture of the problem by looking at its source codes.